# clicking on plus button produces a new edittext in the same view

Tags: android

I am developing an android contacts based application.I have designed the views.I am in problem.When i click on plus button a edittext should appear in the same view
Can anyone help me

My java code is

```
package com.xib;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstScreen extends Activity {
    private Button Back;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);

        Back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn1);
        Back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstScreen.this,SecondScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }


    });
    }
}
```

And my Xml is

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/edit2"
     android:hint=""
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
     android:layout_width="192px"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: Your member naming is horrible. Please don't start field names with an uppercase letter. Also what exactly is not working? The code you are showing us is nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Octavian when i run this code,I have a plus button,I want when i click on plus button an edittext should open existing contact'

Comment: Right, so try that then and come back with a problem.

Comment: Please paste code which is relevant to your question. not some random code :x

Comment: Octavian how to do this??? Mudit how can i get rid of this problem

Comment: There is no problem yet. You have not tried anything as it looks. You have to try it before you get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think his problem is adding dynamic view to his current activity means when the user clicks on plus button, may be he want to add dynamic edit text to his activity. For example in the android contacts while adding new contact there is a plus button whenever we click on that edittext will be added dynamically there so that we can add more contact numbers of a person like mobile, home etc.

Comment: yeah...user 448250 what you are saying is exactly what i have to do